# Convert one object's keys and values into a new type

Tags: typescript

I'm working with a platform that requires me to define an object like this:

```js
interface Source {
  params: Params,
  resolve: (props: ?) => string;
}

const source: Source = {
  params,
  resolve,
}
```

The `params` object is defined like this:

```js
interface Params {
  [key: string]: 'text' | 'number';
}
```

and here's an example of it:

```js
const params: Params = {
  canonical_url: 'text',
  published: 'text',
};
```

This object describes which and what types of params get passed to the `resolve` function:

```js
const resolve: string = (props: ?) => {...};
```

What I'd like to achieve is that the type of `props` for the `resolve` function is derived from the `params` object. For the upper example, the resulting type would be:

```js
interface Props {
  canonical_url: string,
  published: string,  ​
}
```

The other option would be for this to work the other way round. So that the `Props` type defines the object for `params`, but that would mean that TS has to create an actual JS object from a type at transpile time, which I'm not sure is possible.

Comment: You can't do that, because params has type Params which has no specific keys. `{...} as const` would give you more specific information and a mapped type could do e.g. `'text'` -> `string`, but if you're working with third party code it might not be possible to integrate that typing with theirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your interfaces as generics:

```
type Text_ = "text";
type Number_ = "number";

interface Params<T extends Text_ | Number_> {
  [key: string]: T;
}

interface Source<
  T extends Text_ | Number_,
  // this is where we conditionally map 'text' type literal to string type and 'number' to literal to number type
  U = T extends Text_ ? string : T extends Number_ ? number : unknown 
> {
  params: Params<T>;
  resolve: (props: U) => string;
}

const params: Params<Text_> = {
  canonical_url: "text",
  published: "text"
};

const source: Source<Text_> = {
  params,
  resolve: (props) => ""
};

source.resolve(""); // accepts string
source.resolve(1); // number is prohibited
```

Codesandbox example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-murdock-eoplg?file=/src/index.ts:0-527

Comment: Thank you, this helped me out a lot. In my case the type of `props` is an object. Every key in the Params type is also a key in the Props type, it's just the type that changes. I was able to get my type by doing this: `type Props<P = Params> = { [K in keyof P]: P[K] extends 'number' ? number : string };`